# Multiple Rendering Issue on Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, rendering

I am having a strange issue where some elements on a web page are rendered twice, and it seems to be restricted to just using Chrome.

The issue seems to occur when scrolling up and down the page, and results in the element being displayed, but then half of it is repeated directly above itself. It is happening on multiple pages, relating to multiple different sections - so hard to narrow down to one thing. I assumed at first it was a JS issue, but having removed all scripts it is still occuring. The code below is just one example of a section that it keeps happening on:

```
<div class="service-holder">
     <div class="service-image">
          <a class="image-link" href="#"><img src="image-here" alt=""/></a>
      </div>
      <div class="service-text">
           <h2><a href="#">Short Title</a></h2>
           <a class="arrow-link" href="#" title="">Link Here</a>
           <a class="mobile-link" href="#"></a>
      </div>
</div>
```

This block is repeated 3 times, and is basically just a block with an image, Title, and couple of links inside it. The CSS for it is:

```
.service-holder {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: rem-calc(30);
    .service-image {
        .image-link {
            display: block;
        }
        img {
            width: 100%;
        }
    }
    .service-text {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
        padding: rem-calc(20);
        h2 {
            margin-bottom: 0;
            a {
                font-size: rem-calc(42);
                color: #fff;
                font-style: italic;
                font-weight: 600;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                letter-spacing: -0.005rem;
                line-height: rem-calc(30);
            }
        }
        .arrow-link {
            color: #fff;
            font-weight: 600;
            line-height: rem-calc(30);
            letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            &:focus,
            &:hover {

            }
        }
        .mobile-link {
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            z-index: 9999;
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas as to what could be causing this would be helpful! As I said, it is happening on multiple different pages to completely different sections so Im not sure that any of the styling would actually be present throughout.

Comment: Need to see it happening on a live site.

Comment: You should also post the actual css from the live site.

Comment: Yeah I realise it would be more helpful to see it on a live site, but unfortunately wont be able to do that. So thought the css might have something that jumps out as a likely cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right I have found the issue that was causing the Chrome Rendering issues, although it actually wasn't related to the code that I posted in the question - but the solution might help anyone with the same problem.

To Force footer to the bottom of the page, the main content area on each page had the following:

```
 height: 100%;
 overflow-y: auto;
```

Removing these fixed the issue.